# Joomla SMTP Configuration Issue

Tags: smtp, joomla

I'm having an issue with the SMTP setup of my Joomla website when trying to send mass emails through the CB Mailing (Mass Email) extension. I receive this error:

SMTP Error! The following recipients failed:
Number of users to whom e-mail was sent: 0 (Total in list: 1)

So, my question is: 
**What is causing this SMTP error and how can I resolve it?**

The mail log is stating that the email bounces back to the from email: ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org

The only user on the mailing list is user3@earth2525.com (I just ran a test to make sure that the user3 account works and it does). This is the content that comes up in the body of the bounced back email:

```
SMTP Error! The following recipients failed: when sending withTo: , <br />
 (NULL), <br />
 user3@earth2525.com, <br />
Result=true<br />
<br />
```

The old version of this websites mass emailer worked fine, however, in order to add Kunena Forum and maintain compatibility I had to make several upgrades to the site. Both the new version and old verson configurations are outlined below.

**Server for Website:** Mac OS X Server 10.4.11, Apache 1.3.4.1, PHP 5.2.3, MySQL 4.1.22

**Server for SMTP:** Eudora Internet Mail Server 3.3.9 (EIMS Server X)

**New Configuration:**

Joomla 1.5.25,
Community Builder 1.7.1,
CB Paid Subscriptions (CB Subs) 1.2.2,
CBMailing 2.3.4,
Kunena Forum 1.7.0,
Legacy 1.0 plug-in disabled

**Mail Settings (New Config):**

- Mailer: SMTP Server
- Mail from: ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org
- From Name: CASPA
- Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
- SMTP Authentication: Yes
- SMTP Security: None
- SMTP Port: 25
- SMTP Username: ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org
- SMTP Password: xxxxxxx
- SMTP Host: 209.48.40.194

**Old Configuration (Working SMTP Configuration):**

Joomla 1.5.9,
Community Builder 1.2,
CB Paid Subscriptions (CB Subs) 1.0.3,
CB Mailing 2.1,
Legacy 1.0 plug-in enabled

**Mail Settings (Old Config):**

- Mailer: SMTP Server
- Mail from: ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org
- From Name: CASPA
- Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
- SMTP Authentication: Yes
- SMTP Username: ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org
- SMTP Password: xxxxxxx
- SMTP Host: 209.48.40.194

(Notice how the older version of Joomla is missing the 2 fields: SMTP Security and SMTP Port)

Comment: What is the question? What is in the mail log?

Comment: Edited to clarify the question and included mail log info.

Comment: Just to clarify: This is **not** the mail log!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was right under my nose. The problem was that when I upgraded CBMailing the original configuration was reset to default. Most Joomla extensions maintain the existing configuration after an upgrade so I didn't think to even look there at first. So I set it back to the old config and problem solved.

If anyone is interested here is a working CBMailing Config:

- Allow attachments? checked
- Allow HTML? checked
- Method: One e-mail for the whole list
- Send from: A specific address, ctaspa-info@ctaspa.org
- Reply to: The person logged in
- Send to: The list addresses
- BCC recipients: No one